# No fuel pressure

Tags: fuel-system

97 Ford f350 7.3 turbo with duel tank set up ..... I need to know a few things. 1) what can cause no fuel to pump into the fuel bowl, other than the camshaft and the mechanical fuel pump? 2) with a new cam position sensor, I'm not getting any movement on the tachometer. What can cause this? 3) I'm not getting any smoke from the exhaust. but it does come back out of the turbo while trying to start it with WD40 and diesel gas sprayed into the intake through the turbo.

Comment: A year would help. By CPS you mean a cam position sensor? or crank position sensor? You should abbreviate them as CKP and CMP to avoid confusion. Is it a dual tank setup? How about attaching a gauge at one of the filters? How old is the pump it self? If a fuel line is bad you'd only be sucking air when cranking.

Comment: 97, cam sensor, duel tank, and what filters?

Comment: There's a strainer and filter in the fuel filter assembly. I'd make sure the tank selector valve(s) are working and check your lines for air leaks. As it's a mechanical fuel pump unless it's not turning/the diaphragm is ripped you should be seeing fuel pressure unless there's no fuel to pump/the fuel is blocked/or it's sucking air.

Answer (score 1):

No fuel or a weak stream means a bad pump, a plugged fuel filter, fuel line blockage or no fuel in the tank